# is there a way to Auto Generate Tests from Web Services?

Tags: rest, maven, testing, automation, soapui

I have a projects which has a lot of Rest/SOAP Services.
to test them i need to write Tests for each of them. 
I wonder if there is a way for SoapUI to auto generate a basic Tests for all my WebServices, So whenever i add a new WebService to the Application, Soapui generates Tests to this Service.

PS: I am using Soapui maven plugin.

Thanks

Comment: may be you can use online web api testing service some are paid and free. i did not use them but seems but checking their report, looks good and have all necessary data like what peak traffic can handle web api and lot more.

Comment: The SoapUI application will generate sample requests and basic tests for each service listed in a WSDL or WADL.

I haven't used the plug-in you refer to, but I wonder if you can specify WSDL/WADL when creating the test suite to generate the requests and basic tests.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : No, you can't.

Longer answer : Well, maybe. It depends on what you are aiming to test. As a kind of smoketest, you may be able to do something. But proper functional testing is just not possible to autogenerate. Mostly because of the testdata needed. Imagine you want to test a "getCustomerData" serviceoperation. You will probably have a LOT of scenarios that ends up in a "Unknown customer" error. It will be pure luck, if an autogenerated test actually looks up a real customer.

At best you may be able to autogenerate "something that validates according to the schema", and you may be able to use that to smoketest if the service is up and running, by making sure each and every webserviceoperation can be run without returning a HTTP 404.